# Sort based on Factors using Custom Comparator in Java

Tags: java, sorting

Trying to sort the array based on the number of factors using a custom comparator function, but the output remains same as input.
Sorting isnt working

```
    public void solve(){
        Integer[] A = new Integer[]{3,9,4,6,12,10,7}; 

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(A));
        Arrays.sort(A, (A1, B) -> {
            int fact_a = calcFactors(A1);
            int fact_b = calcFactors(B);
            if(fact_a < fact_b) return 1;
            if(fact_a==fact_b){
                if(A1 < B) return 1;
            }
            return 0;
        });
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(A));
    }

    public int calcFactors(int A){
        int count = 0;
        int sqrt = (int)Math.sqrt(A);
        for(int i =1;i<=sqrt;i++){
            if(A%i == 0) count+=2;
        }
        if(sqrt*sqrt == A) count--;
        return count;
    }
```

Comment: I think you should check your lambda expression, there should be some cases in which the return value is -1. In your code, the return value is either 0 or 1, which means the first argument is always equal or greater than the second, so the order will not change.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your comparator only checks for the case that `a < b`.  Properly implemented comparators need to return not only `1` when `a > b`, but also `0` when `a == b` and `-1` when `a < b`.

You could expand your `if` logic to cover those cases, but fortunately, there's an easier way - [Integer.compare()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#compare-int-int-):

```java
int result = Integer.compare(fact_a, fact_b);
if (result == 0) {
  result = Integer.compare(A1, B);
}
return result;
```

`Integer.compare()` handles most of the logic for you; the only thing you need to do is check if the result of the factor comparison is 'equal', and if so, apply the fallback comparison of the numbers themselves

*(note: for the sake of this answer I'm assuming that `calcFactors` is implemented properly...)*

Answer (score 1):

Your comparator should return -1 if `A1` is intended to come before `B` in the sort order, or 1 if `A1` is intended to come after `B`.  Returning `0` should only happen if `A1` and `B` are equal in terms of the sorting.  But you have returned `0` in a lot of cases where `A1` is intended to come after `B`.

I think you intended your logic to be something like this.

```
if(fact_a < fact_b){
     return -1;
}
else if(fact_a == fact_b){
    if(A1 < B) {
       return -1;
    }
    else if(A1 == B) {
       return 0;
    }
    else {
       return 1;
    }
}
else {
    return 1;
}
```

A simpler way of writing this is found in Kevin K's answer, which I have just upvoted.  But this shows you, longhand, what the logic needs to be.